# How can I reuse/dry these routes in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I have these routes

```
  this.resource('politicians'); 

  this.resource('politician', { path: '/politicians/:politician_id', function () {
    // Non nested interface so non nested politician route.

    this.resource('questions', function () {
      this.resource('question', { path: ':question_id' });
    });
  });

  this.resource('questions', function () {
    this.resource('question', { path: ':question_id' });
  });
```

I'd like the question route to be rendered anywhere (using a modal) in the app without losing the current context, but still have a specific/unique url for each question, knowing that the question you got from the nested questions route and the non nested ones are the same.

```
this.resource('question', { path: ':question_id' });
```

The thing is that I don't want to make a custom outlet for that because then I won't have a url for each question.

Comment: Kingpin and I seem to have different interpretations of your question:  Are you looking for a way of having "modal open/closed" referenced in every url (kingpin's answer)?  or are you looking for a way to open a route in a modal without changing url (my answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem is best solved by using query-params and hooking up the modal based on params.  If you don't want to do that you're really stuck with building questions into each route if you want it to be URL based.

Here's an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ucanam/3566/edit

Comment: I have not managed to make query params work yet ^^. Would you have a jsbin with query param and modals?

Comment: Sure, example added above.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Ember's `{{render}}` helper.  Simply place a `{{render 'question' questionModel}}` inside the modal you wish to use.

You can learn about the render helper [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper)

EDIT:

Here is a jsbin to show the basic idea of how to use a render tag in this way.  This jsbin renders the same template in 2 different ways;  Once tied to a route url and once by using the render helper.

[jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/gumoy/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: That assumes questions is always rendered, and wouldn't be URL based

Comment: Non-url based in the modal.  You could still access the route directly via url.  Isn't that what was requested?